# Pre-opening many DBFiles

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox's Sync API in my iOS application. A very simplified feature of my app is that I want users to be able to select .txt files from the DBFilesystem and import these .txt. files into a UITextView.

Preferable, I'd like to construct an NSArray of DBFile objects and work with these. However, in order for me to populate the NSArray, I have to call `[self.filesystem openFile:file error:nill]`, which "opens" all the DBFiles. I notice that opened DBFiles have some restrictions - for example, I can't open a file twice or else I get an error.

Are there other drawbacks to opening many DBFiles at once, or can I safely do it and just make sure not to open a file twice? I'm hoping to treat them sort of like NSFileHandles

If there are drawbacks, I suppose I can create an NSArray of DBPaths, but this is not preferable based on the structure of my application. I can elaborate on this point if necessary.

EDIT: One option is to `close` the file (scroll down from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBFile)). However, a file cannot "open" itself again, which means I will have to use the DBFileSystem to do so again, in which case I might as well make an array of DBPaths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some reasons you may not want to open all files at once. First, when you `open` a `DBFile`, the SDK will automatically start downloading the content, if it's not already cached, and then any new versions as well. Especially if there are many files and/or the user is on a slow or limited data connection, there could be battery and data usage concerns.

Also, the SDK will only actively download so many files at once, and queue up the rest, so if you open everything, the one file the user actually wants at that particular time might be queued behind others they didn't explicitly request.

So, it of course depends on the app, but in general, you won't want to open all of the files at once. Instead, you can just use the file metadata to build your UI, e.g., call `listFolder` to get a list of `DBFileInfo`, and then just open files as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I didn't realize you files automatically download. Do you know if this does so in the background, or if I have to write my own multithreading?

In the end I might just pre-open all the files anyway, considering they are .txt and very small.

Comment: The Sync SDK will automatically download file content in the background for open DBFiles for you. You don't need to do anything, though you also can't disable it. Some relevant info: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBFilesystem.openFile:error:
 https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios#observers

Comment: It sounds like by using observers I can attempt to open files as much as I want while still tracking whether they are fully synced. This fits all my needs. Thanks!